# Cordova Failed to Gradle Bundle Command

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, gradlew

Currently, i m developing hyrbid mobile application for my company. I m planning to upload the .abb (bundle file) to publish in PlayStore. But i failed to run command "gradle bundle". due to error below:

- What went wrong:
  Task 'bundle' is ambiguous in root project 'android'. Candidates are: 'bundleDebug', 'bundleRelease'.

I have successfully run command such as "cordova build android", "gradle bundleDebug" & "bundleRelease". But failed to run "gradle bundle" due to error above. Please advise me. TQ

Comment: Well the task doesn't exist. Is it supposed to exist? It seems the task has variants per build type (debug and release)

Comment: I m very confusing. Kindly advise me, which part not complete either in gradle.build file ?